# Ho to prevent video from overflowing parent container

Tags: angular, sass

I have a resizable container (using [Angular Split](https://github.com/angular-split/angular-split)) which contains a video. I am now trying to add (potentially more than one) overlays to the video, that also resize appropriately with the video, so I created a parent container that holds both the video and the overlays. However, the video keeps overflowing the parent container, leading to the overlays no longer being correct.

What I want instead is for the video to be either the max width or the max height of the parent, without any overflow (also not hidden). So if someone makes the container very small, the video should be very small.

I created a replication of the problem with Stackblitz: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-split-demo-j1k5e3).

My `.ng.html` looks like this:

```html
  <div class="video-wrapper">
              <div class="video">
                <div
                  *ngFor="let overlay of overlays$ | async"
                  [ngStyle]="getOverlayStyle(overlay)"
                  [matTooltip]="overlay.tooltip"
                  class="overlay"
                ></div>
                <video
                  #videoElement
                  class="video-element"
                >
                  <source
                    id="mp4"
                    src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4"
                    type="video/mp4"
                  />
                </video>
              </div>
            </div>
```

My Scss:

```scss
.video-wrapper {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 4px;

  .video {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    justify-self: center;

    .video-element {
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      margin: auto;
      display: table-cell;
    }

    .overlay {
      font-size: 20px;
      z-index: 1;
      position: absolute;
      border: 2px solid;
    }
  }
```

and the relevant part in my component

```js
  readonly overlays$ = of([
    { xMin: 0.1, xMax: 0.9, yMin: 0.3, yMax: 0.5, tooltip: 'hello' },
  ]);

  getOverlayStyle(overlay: Overlay): { [key: string]: string } {
    const width = overlay.xMax - overlay.xMin;
    const height = overlay.yMax - overlay.yMin;

    return {
      top: `${overlay.yMin * 100}%`,
      left: `${overlay.xMin * 100}%`,
      width: `${width * 100}%`,
      height: `${height * 100}%`,
      'border-color': 'red',
      background: 'rgba(255, 0,0,0.1)',
    };
  }
```

Thanks!